# ruby hash block in <main>': undefined method `[]='

Tags: ruby

This works using the hash.update method:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject({}) { |a, i| a.update(i => i) }
```

But this snippet using `a[i] = i`:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject({}) { |a, i| a[i] = i }
```

Results in the following error:

```
<code>NoMethodError: undefined method \`[]=' for 4:Integer
Did you mean?  []
    from (irb):1:in \`block in irb_binding'>
    from (irb):1:in \`each'
    from (irb):1:in \`inject'
    from (irb):1
</code>
```

Would someone please explain to me why I get this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block should return accumulator:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject({}) { |a, i| a[i] = i; a }
#=> {4=>4, 8=>8, 15=>15, 16=>16, 23=>23, 42=>42}
```

This is how `inject` works. The first instance works because `Hash#update` returns updated hash.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out just as you answered. Its kind of obvious when its pointed out :)

Comment: @DjamelHassaine, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Block of inject/reduce must return the new value of accumulator (see @ilya's answer). For some operations this happens naturally, for some - not so much. For those, I prefer `each_with_object` which handles tracking of the accumulator.

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].each_with_object({}) { |i, memo| memo[i] = i }
```

(note that block arguments are in another order here)

#### Bonus

Don't know if you really want to achieve that transformation or it's just a sample code, but if you do, here's another way to do that:

```
ary = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
ary.zip(ary).to_h 
# => {4=>4, 8=>8, 15=>15, 16=>16, 23=>23, 42=>42}
```

Comment: OP: Block arguments for `each_with_object` are in the same order as the method-name `|each, object|`.